# Finding the mean of 2 different values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I would like to find the mean of 2 different values in a column, but I am unsure how to do this. For example, if I had a dataframe, and there was a column named 'color' that was either red or blue, how would I find the mean of all the red items and all the blue items? I am only able to find the mean of the total number of items

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use [`df.groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
df.groupby(['color'])['items'].mean()
```